# Wrong delayed animation of position?

Tags: swiftui

I want to animate the view in the background of the sheet when it is pushed to the top. I have 2 problems:

1. The view jumps to its right position at the first time
2. The button has a weird delay in contrast to the text view

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL85N.jpg

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    @ObservedObject var geopasser = Geo()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Button("show"){
                    show.toggle()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                Text("Test")
            }
            .padding()
            .border(Color.black)
            .offset(y: show ? -geopasser.height * 0.5 : 0)    // <----- position manipolation
        }
        
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut, value: show)     // <----- animation
        .sheet(isPresented: $show, content: {
            VStack{
                GeometryReader{geo in
                    VStack{
                        geopasser.pass(geo: geo)   //   <------- passing sheet height
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Showed \(geo.frame(in: .global).minY)")
                            .presentationDetents([.medium])
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.4)])
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(
                .enabled(upThrough: .fraction(0.4))
            )
        })
    }
}

class Geo: ObservableObject{
    @Published var height: CGFloat
    init(){
        _height = .init(initialValue: 0)
    }
    
    func pass(geo: GeometryProxy)->EmptyView{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.height = geo.size.height
        }
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the buttons pressed down animation occurs at the same time as your position animation and they interfere with one another.

**Solution 1**: Replace the button with a gesture recognizer

```
    VStack{
        Text("show").onTapGesture {
            show.toggle()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        Text("Test")
    }
```

Unless you need specific button behaviour this is the best and the easiest solution

**Solution 2**: Add the .drawingGroup() attribute

```
VStack{
    Button("show"){
       show.toggle()
    }
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    Text("Test")
}.drawingGroup()
```

**Solution 3**: Delay the toggle call

```
VStack{
    Button("show"){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
             show.toggle()
        }
    }
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    Text("Test")
}.drawingGroup()
```

This will delay the animation so the two do not, from the 3 this is my least favourite because I find it a bit hacky

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I tried the solutions. It fixed the button delay but unfortunately it's not the right result because here https://imgur.com/a/68nTvWf you can see, that it is still jumping at the first time.  In addition the box appears very quickly and disappears direct after it